# why can't using loading python27.dll without above Python27/lib py files

Tags: python, visual-c++-6, python-c-api

I have a vc6 application and using python27.dll.

if the runtime environment have python27/lib/* files, it's be ok.

but no python27/lib/* files,the application will termination.

I have using Process Monitor and watch process will load many py. (like os.py...)

and I saw vc6 message window show "**Python failed to load the default activation context**" message. (I trace message occur at dll_main in [dl_nt.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/PC/dl_nt.c))

how to using python27.dll and no other lib/files....?

before using python23.dll , it's run all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For embedding/extending Python 2.7, use one of the newer Visual C++ Express version. I don't think it's compatible with VC 6.